# Keyerror in reading csv file

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to write a script where I pass file name as argument from shell script to python script and python script processes that script.
It is giving me keyerror but if I run the same script hardcoding the file name it works fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOCKFILE=./test.txt
if [ -e ${LOCKFILE} ] && kill -0 `cat ${LOCKFILE}`; then
  echo "already running"
  exit
fi

trap "rm -f ${LOCKFILE}; exit" INT TERM EXIT
echo $$ > ${LOCKFILE}

# do stuff

FILES=/home/sugoi/script/csv/*

for file in $FILES

do
  python ./csvTest.py $file
  #mv $file ./archive


done


rm -f ${LOCKFILE}

exit
```

Python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import csv
import json
import sys

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

for arg in sys.argv: 


 try:
    csvfile = open(arg, 'r')#if i hardcode file name here it works fine
  except IOError as e:
      #write to error log

      sys.exit(100)

  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  header=reader.next()


  for each in reader:
      row={}
      for field in header:

          row[field]=each[field]


  db.test.update({"_id": row["CustomerId"]}, {"$push": {"activities":{"action": row["Action"],"date" :row["Timestamp"],"productId":row["productId"]}}},True)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: check the output of `FILES=/home/sugoi/script/csv/*` in your shell script, I don't think that does what you think it does.

Comment: Why don't you print(arg) to see what the arg variable is set to? This is basic "debugging".

Comment: You can say `for file in /home/sugoi/script/csv/*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues.

1. Your shell script isn't expanding the file list correctly.

`FILES=/home/sugoi/script/csv/*` needs to be something like:

```
FILES=`ls -1 /home/sugoi/script/csv/*;`
```

2. Your argument to the python script will only be one file at a time, so why loop through `sys.argv`?

Just use the argument itself, `sys.argv[1]`. As @Brian Besmanoff pointed out, that needs to be indexed `1` because the script name itself is stored in `sys.argv[0]`.

```
try:
    csvfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
except IOError as e:
    (...)
```

Finally: you can just parse directories with Python instead of looping in a shell script. Look at the `os` module, particularly `os.listdir()`. A little more work and you can have the whole thing running inside one Python script instead of juggling between shell and calling a script.

Answer (score 0):

The first value in `sys.argv` is going to be the name of the script.  [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)